# Location of head.phtml in Magento

Tags: javascript, layout, magento, header

I am working with Magento and need to remove a Javascript that is being included in the `<head>` section by default.

I am using a modified theme called modern. I am looking for head.phtml in:

```
app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page/html/head.phtml
```

It does not exist. I do have header.phtml and footer.phtml. The code from header.phtml starts well after the `<body>` of the document.

Where in the world would the head.phtml file be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17):

Goto Core theme files in Magento : 
**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml**

copy this file from Base and Paste it to you theme, that is

**app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page/html/head.phtml**

Now change here as per your requirement.

To Remove Javascripts goto its XML file i.e. **page.xml**.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 5):

I figured out what the problem was. I needed to look in the base directory under the default template:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html
```

I'm not exactly sure why though.

Comment: This is because Magento's templating system is hierarchical - the modern design will inherit any templates that it does not have from the default design.This is something you will likely want to read more about in the Magento knowledgebase and wiki.

Comment: I spotted this is (in my case too) the correct path of the file to edit.

Comment: You should not edit that file directly. Instead copy it to the same path in your own template and edit your copy.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, JS should usually be removed by commenting/deleting relevant lines from the /layouts files in your theme, not the head template file itself. Unless someone added those script lines manually (naughty code monkey), of course.